# tc / iproute2, how to list the configuration

Tags: linux, iptables, qos, iproute2

This is my first time using traffic shaping and I am wondering how I can list the rules I applied like you can with iptables?

Walter

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Perhaps your problem is that you said "list the rules", while tools from iproute2 use "show" as keyword instead.

Examples:

```
tc qdisc show
tc class show dev eth0
tc filter show dev eth0
```

For more details, consult the manpage for **tc** and the well known resource [LARTC](http://lartc.org/howto/).

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought it was after reading the manpage, but after restarting the router, all of my rules appear to have been deleted.

Comment: To make the rules persistent, have a boot script that sets them during the boot process. How exactly you would do it is highly distribution specific. It's the same with iptables: if you add some rules in the command line and reboot - they get lost. To achieve persistency, you either use iptables-save to save the current rules and iptables-restore during boot, or have a boot script which explicitly calls iptables to set the rules.

Comment: I wished there was something like `iptables-persistent` for persisting tc.