# How to see if any tc/iproute2 rules are in effect?

Tags: networking, debian, iproute2

I've seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/251032/tc-iproute2-how-to-list-the-configuration), but for me on Debian (bookworm), the output is not empty even if I delete everything (`tc qdisc delete dev eth root`) on an interface, `tc qdisc show dev eth` still shows this:

```
qdisc mq 0: root 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :20 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :1f limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :1e limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :1d limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :1c limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :1b limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :1a limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :19 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :18 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :17 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :16 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :15 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :14 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :13 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :12 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :11 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :10 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :f limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :e limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :d limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :c limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :b limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :a limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :9 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :8 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :7 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :6 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :5 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :4 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :3 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :2 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent :1 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5ms interval 100ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn drop_batch 64
```

If these are the default rules, is there any command which would tell me if any manual traffic control is in effect?